# API key for Free implementation of Spotify client

Tags: spotify

I'm building a Raspberry Pi based valve-amplified MP3 player, housed in a restored Westminster radio case:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTabLcVgvwo

I'd like to write a simple Free client that starts playing a particular named playlist ('Westiamp', which is the name of the project) immediately.  It'll also interface to a USB-connected control panel for skipping between tracks, etc.

There will be a simple web UI for entering username and password to log in to Spotify, and WiFi details.

My question relates to the API Key.  There are several options I can see here:

- apply for a personal API key, and release it along with the source code
- apply for an API key for the project, and release it along with the source code
- provide an option in the web UI for the user to specify an API key, and use that

I would much rather not distribute a personal API key, and I don't think usability would be helped by requiring any user of the software to apply for their own key.

Is there a Spotify-approved process here?  I've tried posting on the community forum (silence) and asking support (who directed me here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strictly against the Spotify Terms of Service to distribute your key with source code.

If you're only distributing binaries with the C API key compiled in, that's fine. Otherwise, you must require the end user of your code to supply the C key at compile-time, or ask for the binary key at runtime.

Comment: Yikes, that's not a happy use case for non-developer end-users.  I'd have thought that providing Spotify account credentials would have sufficed.  Thanks for the info though.

Comment: To be fair, it matches the terms pretty much every other API involving API keys I've come across - you can't distribute the key freely. The vast majority of non-developer end users in most cases are only dealing with distributed binaries, so these policies aren't problematic for them.

Comment: Yes - it's not just an issue with Spotify.  The problem is that the very idea of API keys is hostile to Free software, which is sad given how much Spotify builds upon such software itself.  Thus you wind up with workarounds such as asking individual users to apply for API keys themselves :(

Comment: It's been days now since I applied for an API key, and so far: silence.  Presumably anyone who wants to use the client I'm writing will face the same delay?

Comment: Keys are granted automatically and instantly online. See http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/keys/

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I was waiting for a confirmation email.

Comment: Even if an application is compiled, the user can still extract the key using `strings`.